# Catch exceptions from yfinance

Tags: algorithmic-trading, yfinance

I have the following code:

```
try:
    yf.Ticker("AALB.NV").history(period = "3mo")
except:
    pass
```

This gives the exception: - AALB.NV: No data found, symbol may be delisted
Is there any way I can catch this exception?

Answer (score 1):

The `.history()` function doesn't raise an exception if the symbol is invalid, it just prints that statement to your screen. You could raise the exception yourself:

```
import yfinance as yf

try:
    data = yf.Ticker("AALB.NV").history(period="3mo")

    if 'Empty DataFrame' in str(data):
        raise Exception('Empty DataFrame - might be caused by an invalid symbol')

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```